# How to Sort Dates, Numbers, Strings from the array of nested JSON objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

Hi get the JOSN data dynamically, based on the JOSN will render data in the table. In the JSON nested objects come and those names and properties keys also dynamically. I need to sort based on the table columns up and down button action ASC and DESC. On button action, I get the property names to sort, that properties key names will be placed inside the nested objects or it might be in the upper level. How to identify and sort dynamically number, strings or dates. Greate appreciate.

Below logic, I have added only work for the Single level JSON objects, not nested level objects.

```
dynamicJSON.sort((a, b) => {
          if (a[sortKeyname] < b[sortKeyname]) {
            return sortConfig.direction === 'ascending' ? -1 : 1;
          }
          if (a[sortKeyname] > b[sortKeyname]) {
            return sortConfig.direction === 'ascending' ? 1 : -1;
          }
          return 0;
        });
```

Below is the Sample Dynamic JSON data

From the below JSON, I have 7 columns, If I select the status column ASC/ DESC button, I get **statusname** property for the sort. it should traverse and sort nested JSON objects based on the key properties **statusname**. In case, if I select the Details column ASC/ DESC button,I get **maindescription** property for the sort. it should traverse and sort nested JSON objects based on the key properties **maindescription**.

```
[
   {
      "Date":"2020-10-16T04:15:58+00:00",
      "applicationName":"abc Portal",
      "status":{
         "statusname":"Success",
         "style":"success"
      },
      "details":{
         "maindescription":"welcome to the application",
         "maindescriptionSecn":"description 2",
         "maindescriptionSecnthrid":"description 3"
      },
      "location":"Sondekoppa, Karnataka, IN",
      "ipAddress":"157.49.147.190",
      "count":123
   },
   {
      "Date":"2020-10-16T04:15:56+00:00",
      "applicationName":"poratl 1",
      "status":{
         "statusname":"Success",
         "style":"success"
      },
      "details":{
         "maindescription":"welcome to the application",
         "maindescriptionSecn":"description 2",
         "maindescriptionSecnthrid":"description 3"
      },
      "location":"Sondekoppa, Karnataka, IN",
      "ipAddress":"157.49.147.190",
      "count":789
   },
   {
      "Date":"2020-10-16T04:21:41+00:00",
      "applicationName":"app Hub",
      "status":{
         "statusname":"Failure",
         "style":"error"
      },
      "details":{
         "maindescription":"welcome to the application",
         "maindescriptionSecn":"description 2",
         "maindescriptionSecnthrid":"description 3"
      },
      "location":"Sondekoppa, Karnataka, IN",
      "ipAddress":"157.49.147.190",
      "count":666
   }
]
```

Comment: Just wanted to tell you, that your JSON example is not valid. Remove the trailing comma.

Comment: @Rumplin Corrected the format.

Comment: @RameshLamani Do you use redux to do the sorting or just try to sort the entire thing inside a component?

Comment: Wanted to clarify that you would only sort on a single property at a time. That's how your question reads.

Comment: Ive always found it simple and straightforward to build a composite value from the properties you want to sort on that.  It's harder (but not impossible) when the values include numbers and dates.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a closure over the wanted key/keys and direction and use the returned function for sorting.

The sorting funtion uses function which splits the handed over key string by dot and gets the value from the (nested) object.

```js
const
    sortBy = (key, direction = 'ascending') => (a, b) => {
        const
            factor = +(direction === 'ascending') || -1,
            getValue = (object, keys) => keys.split('.').reduce((o, k) => o?.[k], object),
            valueA = getValue(a, key),
            valueB = getValue(b, key);

        return factor * (valueA > valueB || -(valueA < valueB));
    },
    data = [{ Date: "2020-10-16T04:15:58+00:00", applicationName: "IAM Portal/IAM Portal", status: { foo: 'b', statusname: "Success", style: "success" }, details: { maindescription: "welcome to the application", maindescriptionSecn: "description 2", maindescriptionSecnthrid: "description 3" }, location: "Sondekoppa, Karnataka, IN", ipAddress: "157.49.147.190", count: 123 }, { Date: "2020-10-16T04:15:56+00:00", applicationName: "IAM Portal/IAM Portal", status: { foo: 'a', statusname: "Success", style: "success" }, details: { maindescription: "welcome to the application", maindescriptionSecn: "description 2", maindescriptionSecnthrid: "description 3" }, location: "Sondekoppa, Karnataka, IN", ipAddress: "157.49.147.190", count: 789 }, { Date: "2020-10-16T04:21:41+00:00", applicationName: "IAM Portal/Reports Hub", status: { foo: 'c', statusname: "Failure", style: "error" }, details: { maindescription: "welcome to the application", maindescriptionSecn: "description 2", maindescriptionSecnthrid: "description 3" }, location: "Sondekoppa, Karnataka, IN", ipAddress: "157.49.147.190", count: 666 }];

data.sort(sortBy('status.foo'));
console.log(data);

data.sort(sortBy('status.foo', 'descending'));
console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Solutions is closer, how it works for the descending order?

Comment: right, some value for descending sorting was missing. please see edit.

Comment: I tried, descending is not working. Where it is handled descending activities in the logic?

Comment: `factor` is either `1` or `-1` for shaping the direction.

Comment: Can you detailed logic for the ascending and descending?

Comment: it is in this return statement: `return factor * (valueA > valueB || -(valueA < valueB));`

Comment: Above code snippet not working for the descending order, already JSON data is in the descending so displayed as it is. If you keep JSON in ASC order and make for  DESC order with the above logic is not working. Please check it out.

Comment: please have a look to `status.foo`.

Comment: How could retain the original array of a JSON object (initial load JSON data), once we remove the ASC or DESC sort option, I will pass the sort option default.

Comment: i have no idea, what you want.

Comment: For the ascending and descending working fine, in case, if pass default it should return the original array of a JSON object

Comment: that is not possible, because `sort` sorts the array. for getting a default sorting (or original), you could add a property which reflects the original order.

Comment: How could do to reflects the original order?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224213/discussion-between-nina-scholz-and-ramesh-lamani).